# Inductive Proof Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, proof-verification, induction

so I'm working on an algorithms assignment and am having a tough time understanding what to do:

The equation is: $$T(n) = 2T(n/4) + n = \Theta(n) = O(n)$$

Right now I have gotten this far:
$$T(1) = 1$$ This is because T(1) is constant time
`Base Case = 4` so you have $$2T(4/4) + 4$$

My guess is that $$T(n) \leq c*nlogn$$

So my hypothesis is that $$T(n) \leq c*nlogn$$ $\forall n=4,...,k$

This is where I'm stuck. Trying to figure out the inductive step of the solution. 
I have it looking like $$T(k+1) = 2T((k+1)/4) + (k+1)$$

Am I on the right track? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sorry if this isn't formatted correctly, I'm learning $\LaTeX$ and did what I could.

Comment: Your hypothesis does not really make sense. First you observe correctly that $T(n)=\Theta(n)$, which follows directly from the Master Theorem. You are trying to show this inductively, why is your hypothesis $T(n) \le cn\log{n}$? While this is true, you can obtain a tighter bound by hypothesizing $T(n)\le cn$ for an appropriate $c$.

Comment: I had screwed up my equation and was saying that T(n) is supposed to be greater than Theta(n)

Answer (score 1):

The recursion we are trying to solve is

$$T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+n$$

This follows the typical form of the [Master Theorem](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~luebke/cs332.fall00/lecture3/img038.jpg), where

$$T(n) = aT\left(\frac{n}{b}\right)+f(n)$$

and we can [calculate the solution immediately](http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/master-theorem-solver-javascript) as

$$T(n)=\Theta(f(n))=\Theta(n)$$

Suppose we do not have access to the Master Theorem, and we want to prove this inductively. While the inductive hypothesis $T(n) \le cn\log{n}$ is true, since we already know the solution, we can obtain a tighter bound.

Let the inductive hypothesis be $$T(n) \le cn$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and sufficiently large $c$, which is a free constant we can identify later.

The base case is clear, since by assumption $T(1)$ is a constant.

By strong induction, let us assume the claim is true for all integers less than $n$. In particular, it is true for $n/4$. Hence

$$
\begin{align}
T(n) &= 2T(n/4) + n\\
& \le 2c\frac{n}{4} + n && \text{by hypothesis}\\
& = n(\frac{c}{2}+1)\\
& \le cn && \text{for } c\ge2
\end{align}
$$

which completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number $4$
is important in
$T(n) = 2T(n/4) + n$,
let $n = 4^m$.
This becomes
$T(4^m)
=2T(4^{m-1})+4^m
$.

Now,
let
$s(m) 
=T(4^m)
$.
That becomes
$s(m)
=2s(m-1)+4^m
$.
Dividing by $2^m$,
this becomes
$\frac{s(m)}{2^m}
=\frac{s(m-1)}{2^{m-1}}+2^m
$.
Letting
$r(m) = 
\frac{s(m)}{2^m}$,
we get
$r(m)
=r(m-1)+2^m
$
or
$r(m)-r(m-1)=2^m
$.

Summing from
$m=1$ to $M$,
$r(M)-r(0)
=2^{M+1}-2
$.

Unwinding,
since
$r(0) = s(0)
=T(1)
=1
$
and
$r(M)
=2^{M+1}-1
$,
$s(m)
=2^mr(m)
=2^m(2^{m+1}-1)
=2 4^m-2^m
$
so
$T(4^m)
=2\ 4^m-2^m
$
which shows that
$T(n)
=\Theta(n)
$,
at least for powers of $4$.